# @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference cannot get relation data from jsonbackreference model

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jackson

i have a relationship from user and role where role have "one to many" relation and user have "many to one" relation with column "role_id"

when i use relationship on spring boot i got infinite loop data when i use @OneToMany and @ManyToOne so i search and i get @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackRefence. that solved my problem for inifinite loop.

but when i use @JsonManagedReference(for role) and @JsonBackRefence(for user), for role model that work with what i want. like this screenshot :

[image]

but in user model, there are no role data, like this screenshot
[image]

what i want is when i get the role data same as what i want (1 screenshot) and when i get data from user, i want the data like this screenshot : 
[image]

this is my role model :

```
public class Role {
/*
    another data
*/
   @JsonManagedReference(value = "user-role")
   @OneToMany(
           cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           mappedBy = "role"
   )
   private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and my user model :

```
public class User {
   /*
      another data
   */
   @JsonBackReference(value = "user-role")
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="role_id")
   @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
   private Role role;
}
```

i have searched many time in stackoverflow and other website but i didn't find any solution, can you help me to solve my problem, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add annotation other way around

```
@JsonManagedReference(for User) and @JsonBackRefence(for Role)
```

in short, `@JsonBackRefence` will ignore were ever added.

You can refer this for [more detail](https://ashishontech.xyz/jackson-json-infinite-recursion-problem/)

Or see a [Demo](https://profile.ashishontech.xyz/jacksonloop) here with the different use cases.

Comment: that's not solve my problem, when i get "user" data i have "role" data of user, but when i get "role" data, i dont get list "user" of role

Comment: Ohh so you are expecting to get Data both ways. Well with this approach atleast its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not providing the value of the `@JsonManagedReference`

Try doing this:

```
@JsonManagedReference(value = "user-role")
```

and

```
@JsonBackReference(value = "user-role")
```

To exactly specify which reference should be managed.